# Removing a registry key and its subkeys using a batch

Tags: batch-file, registry, key

I need to remove a registry key (including its subkeys) from a batch file.

The examples I found led me to the following code but the key remains?

```
@ECHO OFF
REG DELETE "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R18.0\ACAD-8001:409\Profiles\STDPROFILE" /V
```

Comment: what's the output of that command? (it should give you an error if it failed I think)

Comment: translated from dutch an error occurs that says too little (not enougth comand parameters?

Comment: i replaced /v with /f that seams to do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Not so good at batch programming, but

```
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Autodesk\AutoCAD\R18.0\ACAD-8001:409\Profiles\STDPROFILE" /s > toDelete.txt
for /f %v in (toDelete.txt) do reg delete %v
```

the first line puts every key and value in a file, then the loop reads them and calls reg delete

Comment: you might transform it to a one liner, by `reg query` directly in the `for` command.